# How do you import a whole column from an Access Database to Visual Studio?

Tags: database, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

In my database, I have a column called "Names". I imported my database onto visual studio, and using Visual Basic, I want to be able to import all of the elements of the column "Names" into a combo-box called "rec", but I can't figure it out.
I'm only 16 and new at this, so please be kind.

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you say you imported your database into Visual Studio - is the database still MS Access, or SQLServer, or ... It sounds like you may be able to just specify your current table as the rowsource for the combobox. Yes, you could use VB to loop thru all the names and .Add them to the combobox. Which do you prefer?

Comment: It's still MS Access, I imported it as Data source that's all. How do I loop through all the names and add them to the combobox?

Comment: Why not just specify the 'recordsource' property for your combobox to be the 'names' column from your table. That's by far the easiest method (and you can sort it). If you want VBA code to read a table and populate a combobox, I can provide a sample.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know we can do this :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's Excel to vb. Just cut from Excel and paste into the database.  Make sure it's the same data type.  I did this with baseball stats for an entire season and it worked.